# When the brakes are checked, what do the firemen actually do?

Tags: braking, fire, emergency-services

Watching this [video *(at 06:58 mark)*](http://youtu.be/9KhZwsYtNDE?t=6m58s), this plane had just made a mayday landing, due to a bird-strike. Because of the right engine being shutdown, it was forced to land immediately, with a full load of fuel. The added weight of the fuel, combined with loss of the additional stopping power of reverse thrust, caused the pilots to bear down on the brakes harder and longer than would be normal in an end-of-flight landing.

The pilot requests to hold on a taxi-way after vacating the runway, during which time the firemen come up to the plane to "inspect the brakes."

What do the firemen actually do when inspecting? Are they looking for fire? Glowing brake pads? Do they use an infra-red heat gauge?

Comment: Just a point of clarification, generally its not the actual brakes that catch on fire, but oils such as hydraulic fluid.  The extreme heat can can lines to sever and dump oil onto the brakes.  Hyd fluid burns around 2-3000 C.  That's a bad day.  For this reason, you don't set the parking brake after you stop with hot brakes because you will transfer the heat from the pads across the parking brake clamps and start burning things. The fire department comes out and actually measures the brake temperatures to ensure they aren't at dangerous levels and then cools them with fans.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are specific protocols that procedurally are required to be followed. Insofar as brake inspection is concerned, it would have been obvious from the trucks that there was no brake fire. It's also obvious that there's not a major amount of smoke coming from the brakes. As they approached the landing gear, they would have smelled serious brake heating. Glowing brakes would be seen then if not sooner. A close visual inspection for very light smoke and sensing the heat coming off the brakes would give them an idea of the rate of brake vaporization. It's a subjective judgement based on what they see and feel.

As I understand it, tires that dangerously overheat will explode before melting, and that's why thermal plugs are used which melt and deflate the tire to prevent their exploding.

At a landing in Nandi, Fiji (short runway) with what turned out to be a tailwind in a 747-200 at near-max landing weight, we had to use max braking, and I called for huffers to cool things down, and of course for an inspection. I exited the aircraft as quickly as possible to see how bad things were. I was amazed and alarmed to see thick dark grey smoke pouring from the body and wing landing gear wheels. I thought we were close to having a fire. However, the ground personnel assured me that there was no cause for alarm, that the smoke was just brake vaporization that would shortly stop as they blew air on them. It did, and after refueling we departed without incident.

Comment: How did the passengers react when, after a touchy landing, the CO is the first to evacuate the plane? Serious question.

Comment: @dotancohen It was a freighter, so there were no pax, and it wasn't a matter of evacuating but rather exiting the airplane in the normal matter, which involved lowering a built-in ladder-like stairs in the floor of the upper deck down to the main cargo deck, and then out the airstairs that had been brought to the airplane as usual. Just as a matter of information, if a 747 lands at near-max landing weight at the end of a leg, it's most likely a freighter. Pax 747s rarely land anywhere near max-landing weight unless they're tankering fuel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Terry. I did not mean to be indignant, and I know that for _you_ it was not an evacuation but for any (potential) passengers it may have been _the CO is leaving the craft first_.

Comment: A young FO, aiming for Captain on Vulcans, was tasked to carry out high speed taxi checks.  He bimbled (technical term) down the runway at somewhere around 100 kts, stopped and turned around for another run.  100kts back down the runway and a stop at the other end.  Except it wasn't a stop.  It was a boom, boom, boom as the fusible plugs melted and left a Vulcan up to it's axles in the grass having stopped about 20 metres short of the busy A15 road which ran perpendicular to the threshold of the runway. All the old hydraulic oil made quite a nice fire.  He didn't make Captain.

Comment: Do you know why the use air as opposed to, day, water, to cool the brakes? I suppose it leaves less of a mess on the runway, but in the event there's some spark it seems safer to use water than air

Comment: @raptortech97 I really don't know the answer to that, except to say that air was what we always used. Thinking about it I would guess that the near-explosive generation of steam and shock cooling if you used water would cause problems. Air solves the problem without incurring further problems.

Comment: OK, @Simon, an Avro Vulcan, not a Star Trek one.

Comment: @raptortech97 I'm not a pilot, but from the physics perspective: 1. water could cool things too much, 2. it sprays and you don't see anything, 3. you have to carry the water, but you don't run out of air (a minor problem prbbly).

Comment: When you say "brake vaporization", are you talking about the brake fluid, or is it normal for solid components like brake pads to start vaporizing? Your answer is the only Google hit for `"brake vaporization"`, with quotes.

Comment: @user2357112 It's the solid brake pads that smoke. As I remember, they're carbon, and the smoke is thick and dark, or at least was in that one experience I related.

Comment: Was Nandi the inspiration for the final fate of the 747 in _Wrongful Act_?

Comment: @Sean Now that you mention it, yes, I believe it was, certainly the description noting thick black smoke in the 3rd to the last paragraph of the last chapter. At Nadi, I was amazed at the amount and blackness of the smoke. I thought my career was over for a bit, but the ground crew said it was not an uncommon sight for them. A little bit of vaporized brake material makes a whole lot of black smoke. And in the 2nd to the last paragraph, "Duncan disliked watching airplanes burn" was a nod to my having watched a Cessna 195 burn at the Half Moon Bay airport as a boy in 1953.

Comment: @Terry: Did they ever find out how that Cessna caught fire?

Comment: @Sean I never heard what the formal determination was. The 195 had the Jacobs R-755 engine which as I remember had a history of carburetor fires. The same engine was used in the Cessna AT-17 Bobcat (the bamboo bomber so called). The standard procedure when starting them was to always have a man outside with a fire extinguisher. I saw two carburetor fires on one of them, The SOP was to cutoff the fuel but keep cranking the engine to suck the fire back into the engine. In both instances I observed that took care of the situation and no use of the fire extinguisher was required.

Answer (score 7):

The firemen are looking for fire.  If a blaze does break out, they will extinguish it.

I do not know the protocol for firemen using water to cool the brakes in absence of a visible fire.  Also, it looks to me like the firemen are more interested in the right engine than the brakes.

Comment: you don't want to have the brakes catching fire at the gate while refueling

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm guessing you don't *want* to have the brakes catch fire, ever.

Comment: @falstro ratchetfreak's list of times at which you don't want the brakes catching fire was not exhaustive. :-)

Comment: but it's safer to have them catch fire on a out of the way taxiway than near the gate with all the ground crew

Comment: @ratchet freak:  So there is no benefit to having one of the ground crew run up with a fire extinguisher and put the fire out, before the truck gets there?  I'm not sure the passengers would agree that a big fire out there is better than a small fire next to the gate.

Comment: @SkipMiller It can take ten minutes to taxi to the gate; the fire crews were there within seconds of the plane stopping. Why would you wait until you get to the gate before seeing if the plane was on fire?

Comment: @SkipMiller - I'm with ratchetfreak on this one. If the small fire goes big, much better to have the fire isolated from other people & fuel sources. Ground crews are not trained to run up to a brake fire with a fire extinguisher.

Comment: I believe you don't usually want to use water if it's not necessary, because the thermal shock could make tires blow up.

Comment: They are checking the right engine too because it is damaged and fire could break out there if there was leaking fuel or oil. The fire may have been blown out by blowing air while they flew and might intensify when they stop, so it is also important to check.

Answer (score 5):

Also there is a plug mounted on the wheel so if the brakes heat up the plug melts, so that the tire will not burst.  This would be something they would also check.

Comment: Isn't that a matter of the *tires* heating up rather than the brakes?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Well, the brakes can become really hot and the tires are close enough to get heated from them too. But there is not much to check there; if the plug melts, the tire deflates completely which is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The tires are getting hot because of the huge amount of kinetic energy absorbed by the brakes. They also get a bit of heat from being used (friction from landing) but that's not very big: you can design a tire to take that: after all, your car tires don't get that hot from being driven on.

The brake assemblies act as heat sinks for the kinetic energy absorbed from braking: you have the whole brake assembly heating up to hundreds of degrees, even parts at 800-1,000 C. When you are moving, the air tends to stop the heat from going to the tires. And also to keep the brakes cooler by dissipating the heat. When you stop, the air isn't removing the heat, and radiant plus convective heat transfer from the brakes rapidly heat up the tires, causing the air pressure to increase. The plugs blow to prevent a uncontrolled burst. When you are moving there is no convective heat transfer, because of the air speed: as it heats it is replaced by fresh air. So there is only radiative heat transfer.

This is why tire plugs blow only when the plane is stopped, and the brakes are not being heated anymore by braking, but are actually starting to cool. The heat has to go SOMEWHERE after all, and without a constant stream of air, the tires suffer. After all, they are right next to this massive source of heat energy, at high temperatures. Is like being under a grill.

Some brakes have fans to help the cooling when the plane is stopped, but it's not a standard fit.

The landing gear is designed to prevent wheel burst (or fires) for enough time to allow the firemen to get there to either help cool the landing gear, or else extinguish any fires.

Cooling the brakes properly affects their longevity too: ideally you want them to cool slowly enough to even out any hot spots. Water cooling or even powerful fans can be problem because it can cool some parts too quickly: water mist is suggested.

If you look on the Airbus site, they have some very interesting documents for each plane: Aircraft Characteristics Airport and Maintenance Planning.

[Airbus Aircraft Characteristics Airport and Maintenance Planning](http://www.airbus.com/support/maintenance-engineering/technical-data/aircraft-characteristics/)

There's a section that discusses what aircraft rescue and fire fighting should consider. One part discusses how they should deal with brake overheat and landing gear fire:

[image: Hazard areas]
[image]