# How should ground crews act to safely extinguish an airliner's brake unit fire?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, ground-operations, braking, firefighting

When the brake unit was overheated and had just begun to catch fire due to excessive braking because of long taxi distance upon arrival, the ground personnel (not firefighters) made the first intervention with the fire extinguisher on the parking stand until the firefighters arrive.

I’m wondering, are there any points to be taken into account in terms of ground safety when approaching landing gear during this first intervention or in the case of extinguishing? Is there any guidance procedure for ground crew other than professional firefighters?

What type of extinguisher content should be used to extinguish the fire?

---

Regarding the related post: [How do fire crews handle hot brakes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37167)

I don’t think it’s the same topic. I would like to know if there is a guidance document explaining how the ground crew [not fire crew] should behave in the event of a brake fire upon aircraft arrival.

Comment: The main thing is the big rubber bomb around each of the wheel rims.  Hopefully the thermal fuses will work and let the air out without taking out any bystanders.  I wouldn't go anywhere near a burning wheel myself.  The firefighters are going to approach it with the foam/water cannon while inside the truck.

Comment: I don’t think it’s the same topic. I would like to know if there is a guidance document explaining how the ground crew should behave in the event of a brake fire upon aircraft arrival.

Comment: I've used your comment to highlight the difference, and updated the title accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do fire crews handle hot brakes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37167/how-do-fire-crews-handle-hot-brakes)

Comment: @ymb1 Thank you for making it more understandable on my behalf.

Comment: Don't put yourself alongside the tire. The thermal plugs, if they blow, are going to blow outward from the tire. Stay in front of or behind the tires.

Comment: Why do you think it would be much, if any difference than fire crew guidance about approach path and water given to firefighters?

Comment: @Terry Dear Terry, thank you so much for the valuable information provided.

Comment: @Notts90 Firefighters are exposed to less risk than groun staff only because they are trained to acquire fire fighting skills and have protective clothing. So i’m just trying to learn how this issue to be handled in a safe manner from ground staff perspective.

Comment: @Terry [Boeing says](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/arff/arff737.pdf) to approach at a 45 degree angle. My understanding is the wheel will tend to blow out to the aircraft's left-right axis, the tire itself will blow out foward-aft, so 45 degrees avoids both.

Comment: @user71659 Good info! In the 747 ground schools I attended, at least as I remember them, they didn't cover the tire blowing, saying that the thermal relief plugs would preclude the tire blowing.

Answer (score 2):

Approach from upwind. The source of fire is hot brakes so apply maximum cooling, say water-based. But hydraulic fluids under pressure burn, so if brakes are engaged it's best to ensure with flight crew that the brakes are off as soon as the aircraft is stationary. Stay in the vehicle in case tyre ruptures; chances are it will go sideways. If fuel is leaking, use suitable foam.

I once saw a Harrier with a brake fire.  The burning pressurised brake fluid was acting like a flame thrower on the aircraft structure. The aircraft was written off. This happened about 1981.